# Flask application not reflecting new JS changes

Tags: javascript, python, caching, flask

I have the following code in my Flask server:

```
    res = Response(resp, mimetype='text/plain')
    res.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    res.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    res.headers["Expires"] = "0"

    return res
```

On the client side I have some javascript code (in folder static/JS/) that I am constantly editing while fixing bugs and so on. However the changes I make to the javascript code (example adding an alert or debug statement) do not execute when I refresh the page in a regular chrome window (even when I kill the browser and restart it). This means it continues to run an older (cached copy). The refresh works properly when I use an incognito window. Is there a way so that even the regular browser window can always fetch the latest code? I am concerned that in a production environment the browser will used cached copies and cause an issue.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+R that's for Chrome. You just need to clear cache in browser. Search for it.

Comment: I cant expect an end user to clear cache when any of my JS code changes.

Answer (score 0):

One trick for making sure the browser does not cache a file is to change the url when the file changes. That can be done without changing the filename, by appending a query:

```
<script src="myscript.js?version=7">
```

Or, even better:

```
<script src="myscript.js?timestamp=2837482.2456">
```

You can make a function which generates the URL with the file's actual timestamp. That way, browser will cache it as long as it does not change.

If you are wondering... the query will be ignored. It does not affect static files.